# What is the iPhone 4 user-agent?

Tags: iphone

Has anyone found the iPhone 4's browser's user-agent string yet?

Comment: On this [SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12580745/363573), you can find a generic regular expression to check if a given user agent string is a **iOS 4** one.

Comment: @Stephan: no, you can't. There is no difference between iPhone 3 or 4 or whatever.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

> Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU iPhone OS 4_0 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/532.9 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0.5 Mobile/8A293 Safari/6531.22.7

Comment: not that I don't believe you, but what is your source for this info?

Comment: Here, I found the source, straight from Apple:
http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/appleapplications/reference/safariwebcontent/OptimizingforSafarioniPhone/OptimizingforSafarioniPhone.html

Comment: How can I find the user agent of the current device through the code?

Comment: @Shri - Put your last in a new question, not a comment of an answer to a related question.

Comment: This is no valid answer anymore! iPhone OS 4_0 is a long time ago, so already with a upgrade of iOS this answer would be invalid.

Comment: I got `iPhone OS 4_0` today from my iPhone 7 and I have no idea how or why!

Answer (score 9):

You can use:

http://whatsmyuseragent.com/

To find your user agent (Google: "What is my user agent" gives this answer)

Comment: iPhone 4 won't be released until tomorrow.

Comment: People have received shipments as early as yesterday

Comment: Maybe my answer is not completely right if you wanted to know iPhone4 User-Agent without owning one (because you were analyzing web server logs or something), but I wanted to show and *document* how to get the user-agent from any device connected to Internet. Hope it helps to someone.

Comment: its totally right; and there isn't a difference between a 3gs, 3g and iphone4 all running ios4. It's still "iPhone"... if you google the reported user-agents of iphone4's or go to whatsmyuseragent.com with a 3g(s) updated to ios4 it's the same user agent.

Comment: @Charles, My iPhone 4 arrived at 10:00 this morning.

Answer (score 9):

- Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU iPhone OS 4_0 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/532.9 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/7D11
- Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU iPhone OS 4_0 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/532.9 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0.5 Mobile/8A293 Safari/6531.22.7
- Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU iPhone OS 4_0_1 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/532.9 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0.5 Mobile/8A306 Safari/6531.22.7
- Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU iPhone OS 4_1 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/532.9 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0.5 Mobile/8B5097d Safari/6531.22.7
- Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU iPhone OS 4_2 like Mac OS X; en_us) AppleWebKit/525.18.1 (KHTML, like Gecko)
- Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU iPhone OS 4_2_1 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/533.17.9 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.0.2 Mobile/8C148 Safari/6533.18.5

...for now

Answer (score 3):

iOS 4.3.2's User Agent, which came out this week, is:

> Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU iPhone OS 4_3_2 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/533.17.9 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.0.2 Mobile/8H7 Safari/6533.18.5

Answer (score 3):

This site seems to [keep a complete list that's still maintained](http://www.enterpriseios.com/wiki/UserAgent)

iPhone, iPod Touch, and iPad from iOS **2.0 - 5.1.1** (to date).

You do need to assemble the full user-agent string out of the information listed in the page's columns.

Comment: Interesting list, but it's only valid for ActiveSync.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot identify the (hardware) version of an iPhone by user agent.

It's only possible to recognize that it's an iPhone and which software versions it's running.

[Using the Safari User Agent String](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/OptimizingforSafarioniPhone/OptimizingforSafarioniPhone.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006517-SW3)

Not even [WURLF](http://wurfl.sourceforge.net/) can.

Answer (score 0):

Note: The user agent strings from Facebook's internal browser *do* indicate the actual physical device. Even the cellphone carrier (eg. AT&T)

Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 10_3_3 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/603.3.8 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/14G60 [FBAN/FBIOS;FBAV/149.0.0.39.64;FBBV/79173879;FBDV/**iPhone7**,2;FBMD/iPhone;FBSN/iOS;FBSV/10.3.3;FBSS/2;FBCR/AT&T;FBID/phone;FBLC/en_US;FBOP/5;FBRV/0

Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 11_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/604.3.5 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/15B93 [FBAN/FBIOS;FBAV/148.0.0.45.64;FBBV/78032376;FBDV/**iPhone10,4**;FBMD/iPhone;FBSN/iOS;FBSV/11.1;FBSS/2;FBCR/AT&T;FBID/phone;FBLC/en_US;FBOP/5;FBRV/0]

These won't be the case in Safari or Chrome from iOS - only within the browser inside the Facebook app.

(I'm getting `iPhone9` too though - not quite sure what that is!)