# Screen size in JSP/Servlet

Tags: web-applications, servlets, mobile, screen-size

Is there a way to get the client screen size in a web application? I need to write a web application using `JSP/Servlets` that will be used by different types of clients (I mean cell phones, iPad, laptops, etc.). I read on more links from here, like this ones:

- [Detecting Device Type in a web application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8515161/detecting-device-type-in-a-web-application)
- [How do I check if the useragent is an ipad or iphone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5155479/how-do-i-check-if-the-useragent-is-an-ipad-or-iphone)
- [Auto detect mobile browser (via user-agent?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005153/auto-detect-mobile-browser-via-user-agent)

but taking in account that there is no standard way to detect the device type, I started to think if isn't a better solution to decide the page that will be served based on the screen size.

So, my **question**: is there a way to detect the screen size in `JSP/Servlets`?

N.B. I read also about `CSS3` capabilities - media queries, but I think that I need something else as long as I will need lesser content in the page in cell phone case. I also think that taking a decision based on the screen size, is an easier choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that I found the answer to my question. Take a look at [this](http://blogs.developerforce.com/developer-relations/2012/05/cross-device-html5-apps-using-visualforce.html) web posting, especially *Client-Side Device Detection with Screen Size and/or Device Features* paragraph.