# Only allow ipad application users to reach certain files

Tags: c#, ios, asp.net, iphone, ipad

I have an asp.net web project where it acts as a web service for my ipad application. I show pdf files from servers public address in my ipad project with UIWebView. I added the folder to hidden segments in web config but this rejects all incoming requests.  what i need right now is to reject users trying to access pdf files from web browser and only allow logged in users of ipad application to view the files in a uiwebview.

Comment: This will answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5155479/how-do-i-check-if-the-useragent-is-an-ipad-or-iphone

Comment: This would allow users on ipad safari browser to see my files though. I want only my registered and accepted app users to be allowed to see the pdf files.

Comment: How do they log in to your application? Can you send a cookie with the request indicating the source?

Comment: they enter the email address and password to server's currently public web service's login function with post method and if server sends "True" then userid and loggedin info is kept in ipad's memory. I haven't applied token based application yet for we are still testing the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `OAuth2` for `Authentication` at time of `login`.

When iPad app will use [AFNetworking Extension for OAuth 2 Authentication](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFOAuth2Client) to make request which will provide `accessToken` for `each user differently`.

To `excess file` `user` will have to `provide` `accessToken` to `access files`.