# What is iphone's indicator flag for user agent?

Tags: iphone, user-agent

What is the indicator flag for iphone default browser's (safari) user agent like IE9 for internet explorer 9 and FF3 for firefox 3 and so on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this help you: http://www.zytrax.com/tech/web/browser_ids.htm#safari

Answer (score 2):

```
Mozilla/5.0 (iPod; U; CPU iPhone OS 4_0 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/532.9 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0.5 Mobile/8A293 Safari/6531.22.7
```

^^ User-Agent String for iPhone 4 w/ **IP4** <-- Indicator Flag

```
Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; U; CPU OS 3_2 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/531.21.10 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0.4 Mobile/7B334b Safari/531.21.10
```

^^ User-Agent String for iPad w/ **iPad** <-- Indicator Flag

Answer (score 0):

I think you can safely use iPhone.

For details see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3105555/what-is-the-iphone-4-user-agent) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2153877/what-is-the-ipad-user-agent).