# how do I parse a mobile site with php file_get_content

Tags: php, mobile

Sorry if this is a duplicate question.
My target site redirects me to desktop site if the browser is not a mobile. I want to parse the mobile version of the site (http://mobile.mysite.com). I can't use Curl as my server is disabled for that.
what would be the useragent for mobile if it is possible at all ??!!

Comment: Every browser has a different user agent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to send custom headers like `User-Agent` with your `file_get_contents` request, the PHP answer to that are *stream contexts*:

```
$opts = array(
    'http' => array(
        'method' => "GET",
        'header' => "Accept-language: en\r\n" .
                    "Cookie: foo=bar\r\n" .
                    "User-Agent: Foo Bar Baz\r\n"
    )
);

$context = stream_context_create($opts);

file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
```

See [`stream_context_create`](http://php.net/stream_context_create) and [`file_get_contents`](http://php.net/file_get_contents).

Comment: I know this code but for https link somehow it returns desktop page

Answer (score 0):

Pick a mobile User-Agent string and use it. They can easily be [found from Google](http://www.google.com/search?mobile+user+agent).

Here is some sample code that illustrates how to use them with `file_get_contents()`:

```
<?php

   // The first one I found on Google
   $uaStr = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 2.2; en-us; Nexus One Build/FRF91)';

   // Create a stream context
   // http://www.php.net/manual/en/context.http.php
   $context = stream_context_create(array(
     'http'=>array(
       'user_agent' => $uaStr
     )
   ));

   // The URL
   $url = "http://www.example.com/";

   // Make the request
   $result = file_get_contents($url, FALSE, $context);
```

Answer (score 0):

try look this php libs:

[PHP HttpClient](http://scripts.incutio.com/httpclient/)

And if you want get mobile site, set the user agent to specific mobile browser

```
$userAgent = "NokiaC5-00/061.005 (SymbianOS/9.3; U; Series60/3.2 Mozilla/5.0; Profile/MIDP-2.1 Configuration/CLDC-1.1) AppleWebKit/525 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/3.0 Safari/525 3gpp-gba";
setUserAgent($userAgent);
```

Answer (score 0):

To change your user agent within php without curl you may try this:

```
<?php
ini_set('user_agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU iPhone OS 4_0 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/532.9 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0.5 Mobile/8A293 Safari/6531.22.7');
$data = file_get_contents("http://www.mobile.example.com");
?>
```

PS: Got user agent of the iphone 4 from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3105555/what-is-the-iphone-4-user-agent) !