# What is the iOS 6 user agent string?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, user-agent, ios6

What is the ***iOS 6.0*** user agent string?

---

Previous user-agent strings:

- [**iOS 5.1** - What is the iOS 5.1 user agent string?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10152433/836407)
- [**iOS 5.0** - What is the iOS 5.0 user agent string?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7825873/836407)
- [**iOS 4.0** - What is the iPhone 4 user-agent?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3105555/836407)

Comment: On this [SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12580745/363573), you can find a generic regular expression to check if a given user agent string is a **iOS 6** one.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

iPhone:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 6_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/536.26 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/6.0 Mobile/10A5376e Safari/8536.25
```

iPad:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 6_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/536.26 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/6.0 Mobile/10A5376e Safari/8536.25
```

---

For a complete list and more details about the iOS user agent check out these 2 resources:
[Safari User Agent Strings (http://useragentstring.com/pages/Safari/)](http://useragentstring.com/pages/Safari/)
[Complete List of iOS User-Agent Strings (http://enterpriseios.com/wiki/UserAgent)](http://enterpriseios.com/wiki/UserAgent)

Comment: your second link is crazy. i have never seen those "user-agent prefixes" anywhere, not even on your examples!

Comment: @gcb I also have no clue what those User Agent Prefixes are. I have never seen them in any iPhone User Agent String.

Answer (score 4):

Some more:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 6_1_3 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/536.26 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/6.0 Mobile/10B329 Safari/8536.25

Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 6_1_4 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/536.26 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/6.0 Mobile/10B350 Safari/8536.25
```