# How to detect iOS 6 and all minor versions by user agent?

Tags: ios, regex, user-agent, ios6

How to detect iOS 6 and all minor versions by user agent with a simple regex or something? Would be nice to distinct between iphone and ipad as well.

---

This question differs from [What is the iOS 6 user agent string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12305566/what-is-the-ios-6-user-agent-string) since I wanted help in building a regex based on the information I already know (which can be found in the linked question)

Comment: Are you looking for any arbitrary iOS 6 user agent, or just Safari?

Comment: Ideally all possible user agents but since Safari is the most common I think it may be a startpoint :)

Comment: Just to point out, user agents are easily spoofable.

Comment: Thanks for your hint, but if somebody spoofs his user agent I am not willing to provide him with out cool device specific feature, so it's okay for my purposes.

Comment: Have you got some sample usser agent strings ?

Comment: @Stephan Added link to another SO question with lists of user agent strings as answer. Any ideas how to detect these with some regexes? Thanks

Comment: @dasheddot I have send an answer with a generic regex that should help you.

Comment: It's no duplicate, cause I wanted help in building a regex with the information I already know (that's what the duplicate question asks)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

**CHANGELOG**

> **20/01/2017**
>
> - UA strings update: 141 matching, 0 partially matching, and 797 invalid lines
> - "Mobile Safari 1.1.3 (iPhone U; CPU like Mac OS X; en)" is considered invalid even if it mentions iPhone. Actually a semi-colon is missing after the `iPhone` term which is suspicious.
> - Safari 8+ doesn't appear yet on UserAgentString.com

**PREREQUISITES**

- The following regex is generic.
- It will match Safari user agent strings (SUAS) running on a mobile device (see below supported devices list).
- The regex is based on known SUAS by [UserAgentString.com](http://useragentstring.com/pages/useragentstring.php?all=TRUE&name=Safari&vers=) as of **20/01/2017**.

**REGEX**

```
^(?:(?:(?:Mozilla/\d\.\d\s*\()+|Mobile\s*Safari\s*\d+(?:\.\d+)+\s*)(?:iPhone(?:\s+Simulator)?|iPad|iPod);\s*(?:U;\s*)?(?:[a-z]+(?:-[a-z]+)?;\s*)?CPU\s*(?:iPhone\s*)?(?:OS\s*\d+_\d+(?:_\d+)?\s*)?(?:like|comme)\s*Mac\s*O?S?\s*X(?:;\s*[a-z]+(?:-[a-z]+)?)?\)\s*)?(?:AppleWebKit/\d+(?:\.\d+(?:\.\d+)?|\s*\+)?\s*)?(?:\(KHTML,\s*(?:like|comme)\s*Gecko\s*\)\s*)?(?:(?:Version|CriOS)/\d+(?:\.\d+)+\s*)?(?:Mobile/\w+\s*)?(?:Safari/\d+(?:\.\d+)*.*)?$
```

**SUPPORTED DEVICES LIST**

- iPhone
- iPhone Simulator
- iPad
- iPod

**EXPLANATION / CUSTOMIZATION**

*Lines preceded by a **C** can be customized.*

```
  1. ^(?:(?:(?:Mozilla/\d\.\d\s*\()+|Mobile\s*Safari\s*\d+(?:\.\d+)+\s*)
C 2.     (?:iPhone(?:\s+Simulator)?|iPad|iPod);\s*
  3.     (?:U;\s*)?
  4.     (?:[a-z]+(?:-[a-z]+)?;\s*)?
  5.     CPU\s*
  6.          (?:iPhone\s*)?
C 7.          (?:OS\s*\d+_\d+(?:_\d+)?\s*)?
C 8.          (?:like|comme)\s*Mac\s*O?S?\s*X
  9.      (?:;\s*[a-z]+(?:-[a-z]+)?)?
  10. \)\s*)?
  11. (?:AppleWebKit/\d+(?:\.\d+(?:\.\d+)?|\s*\+)?\s*)?
C 12. (?:\(KHTML,\s*(?:like|comme)\s*Gecko\s*\)\s*)?
C 13. (?:(?:Version|CriOS)/\d+(?:\.\d+)+\s*)?
  14. (?:Mobile/\w+\s*)?
  15. (?:Safari/\d+(?:\.\d+)*.*)?$
```

**line 1.** UA strings may differ so this line is introduced for accepting UA strings as much as possible.
**line 2.** You can specify here the piped-separated list of accepted devices.
(...)
**line 7.** The version is indicated here. Change this line if you want a special version. Don't forget to update **line 13** too. For instance, matching *iOS 5.x.y* use `(?:OS\s*5_\d+_\d+\s*)?`.
**line 8.** Some user agent strings are translated. The word `like` may be translated into a foreign language. The regexp now supports `English` and `French`. Adapt this line if you encounter other languages. Don't forget to update **line 12** too.
(...)
**line 12.** See **line 8.**
**line 13.** See **line 7.** For instance, matching *iOS 5.x.y* use `(?:Version/5\.\d+\.\d+)?\s*)?`.

Comment: Really cool!! Thank you so much for this high-quality answer on my not-so-high-quality question ;) Upvoted and marked as solution. Thanks!

Comment: @Stephan: Np, but there's more actually: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12861494/89771 (see the comments).