# iOS detection using regex in PHP

Tags: php, regex

I came here searching for an answer to sniffing for iOS 6 via the useragent and found a wonderful answer here: [How to detect iOS 6 and all minor versions by user agent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12567260/how-to-detect-ios-6-and-all-minor-versions-by-user-agent/12580745#12580745)

All regular expressions I've worked with previously have been pretty simple and I'm banging my head against a wall trying to get this one working properly. Unfortunately the PHP parser isn't giving me any errors!

I know for a fact I'm doing something wrong, since I'm getting a match for the code below while running firefox on my laptop.

I would appreciate if anyone could point me in the right direction here, I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

```
$subject = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
$pattern = '~^(?:(?:(?:Mozilla/\d.\d\s*()+|Mobile\s*Safari\s*\d+.\d+(.\d+)?\s*)(?:iPhone(?:\s+Simulator)?|iPad|iPod);\s*(?:U;\s*)?(?:[a-z]+(?:-[a-z]+)?;\s*)?CPU\s* (?:iPhone\s*)?(?:OS\s*\d+\d+(?:\d+)?\s*)?(?:like|comme)\s*Mac\s*O?S?\s*X(?:;\s*[a-z]+(?:-[a-z]+)?)?)\s*)?(?:AppleWebKit/\d+(?:.\d+(?:.\d+)?|\s*+)?\s*)?(?:(KHTML,\s*(?:like|comme)\s*Gecko\s*)\s*)?(?:Version/\d+.\d+(?:.\d+)?\s*)?(?:Mobile/\w+\s*)?(?:Safari/\d+.\d+(.\d+)?)?.*$~';

if (preg_match($pattern,$subject))
{
    echo "match";
}
```

Comment: What does `var_dump( $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);` output?

Comment: @nickb Obviously depends on what device/browser I'm using, but in Firefox on my laptop: string(83) "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.8; rv:15.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/15.0.1"

It's not supposed to match that!

Comment: Obviously. The point is the regex is faulty - It does indeed match that user agent, when clearly it is not the correct behavior.

Comment: @nickb Ack, I figured with the detail and instructions the guy put into his reply that it worked properly!

Comment: @nickb especially as that user had checked it as a correct answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this instead :

```
^(?:(?:(?:Mozilla/\d\.\d\s*\()+|Mobile\s*Safari\s*\d+\.\d+(\.\d+)?\s*)(?:iPhone(?:\s+Simulator)?|iPad|iPod);\s*(?:U;\s*)?(?:[a-z]+(?:-[a-z]+)?;\s*)?CPU\s*(?:iPhone\s*)?(?:OS\s*\d+_\d+(?:_\d+)?\s*)?(?:like|comme)\s*Mac\s*O?S?\s*X(?:;\s*[a-z]+(?:-[a-z]+)?)?\)\s*)?(?:AppleWebKit/\d+(?:\.\d+(?:\.\d+)?|\s*\+)?\s*)?(?:\(KHTML,\s*(?:like|comme)\s*Gecko\s*\)\s*)?(?:Version/\d+\.\d+(?:\.\d+)?\s*)?(?:Mobile/\w+\s*)?(?:Safari/\d+\.\d+(\.\d+)?.*)?$
```

Demo : http://gskinner.com/RegExr/?32eou

A even more generic solution : http://code.google.com/p/php-mobile-detect/

Comment: Warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Compilation failed: range out of order in character class at offset 243

Comment: @nmford: Did you add the delimiters?

Comment: @nmford: I guess I double pasted or something, try again.

Comment: The script parses now, but it still matches for firefox on my laptop which it shouldn't. Starting to think that perhaps I should just put something simpler together myself!

Comment: @nmford: Matches Firefox because of the `Mozilla` and since everything else is optional... You should use atomic groups. Or better yet, don't reinvent the wheel: http://code.google.com/p/php-mobile-detect/.

Comment: Hah, thanks Alix. Probably the best way to go. I voted this answer up for that comment, perhaps edit your answer to reflect it?

Comment: @nmford: No problem. Just out of curiosity, may I ask where you picked up `~` for the PCRE delimiters? I've been using them for years, and lately I've been seeing them used everywhere!

Comment: Saw it mentioned on here once and have been using them since!

Comment: @Stephan: Still, doesn't seem to match anything.

Comment: @AlixAxel I have updated the demo. It runs fine now. I noticed that the original cut/paste regex in your answer had some meta characters left out.

Answer (score 3):

The regex had some error. Some metachars has gone because of SO character escaping system.

Here is the PHP code of your question updated :

```
$subject = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
$pattern = '~^(?:(?:(?:Mozilla/\d\.\d\s*\()+|Mobile\s*Safari\s*\d+\.\d+(\.\d+)?\s*)(?:iPhone(?:\s+Simulator)?|iPad|iPod);\s*(?:U;\s*)?(?:[a-z]+(?:-[a-z]+)?;\s*)?CPU\s*(?:iPhone\s*)?(?:OS\s*\d+_\d+(?:_\d+)?\s*)?(?:like|comme)\s*Mac\s*O?S?\s*X(?:;\s*[a-z]+(?:-[a-z]+)?)?\)\s*)?(?:AppleWebKit/\d+(?:\.\d+(?:\.\d+)?|\s*\+)?\s*)?(?:\(KHTML,\s*(?:like|comme)\s*Gecko\s*\)\s*)?(?:Version/\d+\.\d+(?:\.\d+)?\s*)?(?:Mobile/\w+\s*)?(?:Safari/\d+\.\d+(?:\.\d+)?.*)?$~';

if (preg_match($pattern,$subject))
{
    echo "match";
}
```