# Is there a media query or CSS hack to target iOS6 mobile Safari?

Tags: css, ios6, mobile-safari

Is there a media query or hacky CSS selector for iOS6 mobile Safari?

I need to apply specific CSS to iOS6. Long story short: I am styling the select element, and iOS6 in all of my tests is the only OS in which my solution does not work, and I need to do something different for it, which is, let it be itself. No judgment please.

Mobile Safari in iOS7 is fine.

Comment: You could check the user agent in javascript and style conditionally http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12305566/what-is-the-ios-6-user-agent-string

Comment: No intention to doubt your need of a selector, but may I ask exactly what rules are causing the problem - or what kind of misrendering you are encountering?

Comment: Hi Anders, I am using a SVG image as background image for the select element. This work in IE10, IE11, Chrome, Firefox, iOS7, but not iOS6. iOS6 does not show the image. You can see the select element on this page: http://skeleton.myshopify.com/collections/all