# Javascript if Iphone 5 or higher

Tags: javascript, iphone, version, detect

Is there a way to tell if a user with iphone is using a 5 or higher version of the phone? The pixel ratio is the same on the 4 / 5 so I can't use that.

I need to do this with JS because I have functions that I wan't to disable if lower than 5.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detecting iPhone 5 and any iOS device below it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12505618/detecting-iphone-5-and-any-ios-device-below-it)

Comment: Also, while not a proper answer, you might still want to look at **[the tutorial](http://www.jquerybyexample.net/2013/03/detect-iphone-version-using-jquery-javascript.html)** he copied it from.

Comment: @Cerbrus Should I accept his answer as the correct one?

Comment: No. You shouldn't, that would encourage people to simply copy tutorials.